# what does Telepresence's DIAL_REJECT code error means?

Tags: http, telepresence

So I'm using [telepresence](https://www.telepresence.io/) to intercepte HTTP connections, but I keep getting this error :

```
│ 2022-02-01 22:26:51.8378 info    forward : Accept got connection from xxx.xx.x.x:xxxx : lis=":9900"                                                                                                       
| 2022-02-01 22:26:53.9516 error   forward : !! CONN tcp xxx.xx.x.x:xxxx -> 127.0.0.1:xxxx: unhandled connection control message: code DIAL_REJECT, len 0 : lis=":9900"                                        
| 2022-02-01 22:26:56.8242 error   forward :    CONN tcp xxx.xx.x.x:xxxxx -> 127.0.0.1:xxxx stream-to-conn loop ended because it was idle for too long : lis=":9900"
```

I would like to know what this error means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved, That means the port I target is not listening.